# Angular routing not work correctly with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

In my Angular application, when I open link localhost:4200 (application serve on it), I want that my application redirect me on localhost:4200/notes. And I want to see data of notes-component, which is contained in main component.

**Example (text in html page):**

```
App component
Main component
Notes-page component
```

But I only can see localhost:4200 (without redirect) and data of notes-component, without main component.

**Example (text in html page):**

```
App component
Notes-page component
```

Why it works like this? And how I can correct it?

**Files structure:**

```
/app
  /containers
    /main
      /notes-page
        notes-page.routing.ts
        notes-page.component.ts
        notes-page.module.ts
    main.routing.ts
    main.component.ts
    main.module.ts
  app.routing.ts
  app.component.ts
  app.module.ts
```

**Files:**

app.routing.ts

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './containers/main/main.module#MainModule'
  }
]);
```

app.component.html

```
<h5>App component</h5>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

main.module.ts

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'notes',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'notes',
        loadChildren: './notes-page/notes-page.module#NotesPageModule'
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

main.component.html

```
<h5>Main component</h5>
<main> 
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

notes-page.module.ts

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: NotesPageComponent
  }
]);
```

notes-page.component.html

```
<h5>Notes-page component</h5>
```

Comment: add pathMatch: 'full'  here : path: '',
    loadChildren: './containers/main/main.module#MainModule'

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
    - app.routing.ts file should have MainComponent imported here and imported in app.module.ts:

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'notes', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {
          path: 'notes',
          loadChildren: './notes-page/notes-page.module#NotesPageModule'
        }
    ]
  }
]);
```

You don't need main.module.ts

Comment: No, it didn't help me. It's working like above. But thanks for answer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that... I had same scenario couple of months ago, and it worked for me. It showed data from appcomponent, maincomponent and notescomponent. Strange...

Comment: At least does it redirect you to 'notes' route?

Comment: No, I don't understand why, but it stay on /.